# Need help on flippingHorizontal assignment

Tags: java, image, pixel

I am trying to flip a square image inside a picture with user input variables. After running the code nothing happens at all. In other attempts I was able to make a small thin rectangle appear. How do I fix this?

```
     public void flipHorizontal (int x, int y, int size)

  {
    int half = size / 2;
    int x1 = x - half;
    int y1 = y - half;
    int x2 = x + half;
    int y2 = y + half;
    Pixel sourcePixel = getPixel (x1,y1);
    Pixel targetPixel = getPixel (x1, y1 + half);

    //loop through columns
    for (x = x; x < x2; x++)
    {
      //loop from 0 to before mirror point
      for (y = y; y < y2 + half; y++)
      {
        Color friend = sourcePixel.getColor();
        sourcePixel = getPixel (x1,y1);
        targetPixel = getPixel (x1, y1 + half);
        targetPixel.setColor (friend);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use method arguments as your loop variables...? And your second assignments of `sourcePixel` and `targetPixel` in the loop don't make sense, as the variables they're dependent on don't change. Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Regarding hardly anything coming up: what values are you inputting to this method? You have int x1 = x - half, and int x2 = x + half. The problem with this is that for x1, any x < half will result in a pixel that is off canvas (x will be negative). Similarly, for x2,  x > half also results in a pixel that is off canvas (x is larger than the canvas). If you aren't checking your bounds, this can mess up your image big time.

Comment: My apologies, i posted an older version of the file that I had and I did not check it over. Thanks for pointing out the variable dependency because it flew over my head, that solved my issue. Thanks.